# Passport-facebook giving localhost in url

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=27738156*******

In the above url localhost is still coming even after i changed the callback url in passport strategy and on facebook developer id too. Also i changed the app domain "localhost" to my website domain. Still receiving the same error.
 NEED HELP GUYS!!

Here is my code:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID  :  configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id','email', 'first_name','last_name'],
    passReqToCallback : true,
    enableProof: true
},


function(req,token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        console.log(token);
        var query = {email: profile.emails[0].value};
        var update = {$set: {
            facebookid:profile.id,
            firstname:profile.name.givenName,
            lastname:profile.name.familyName,
            provider:profile.provider
        }};
        var options = {new:true,upsert:true};

        User.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,options,function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;
            return done(null,user);
        });


}));


    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook',{scope:['email']}),function(req,res,next){});

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect : '/1.html'}),

       function(req,res,next){
           console.log(req.session);


           res.redirect('/main.html');
       } 

    );

-->auth.js


module.exports = {

'facebookAuth' : {
    'clientID'      : '27738156*******', // your App ID
    'clientSecret'  : '**************************', 
    'callbackURL'   : 'http://mywebsite.com/users/auth/facebook/callback'
},
```

Comment: Can you show your FacebookStrategy code? and are you sure have given requried callback url on facebook app?

Comment: Now you can check the code! @abdulbarik

Comment: I am still not able to see your config code of `configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL`. I am sure there is some mismatch with your callback URL and your app callback URL

Comment: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL is accessing from auth.js file. @abdulbarik

Comment: make sure to check your `configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL` value is proper url which you want

Comment: I Double checked that thing still getting that error! :( @abdulbarik